# Saving node coordinates (layout) in igraph

Tags: igraph, gephi

I have a calculated graph layout of a large graph. I would like to load this graph, as well as its layout (coordinates) in Gephi. Is there a file format that is supported by both igraph and Gephy that allows coordinates specification?

Answer (score 0):

GraphML should be okay - just assign the x and y coordinates of the nodes as two vertex attributes (say, `x` and `y`) in igraph and then load the graph in Gephi. I'm pretty sure Gephi provides a way to use numeric vertex attributes as coordinates for a layout.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a file format that is supported by both igraph and Gephy that allows coordinates specification?

Any format that supports node-attributes.

> I would like to load this graph, as well as its layout (coordinates) in Gephi.

Placing nodes corresponding to their coordinates is possible using the [GeoLayout plugin](https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/geolayout-plugin).